# Fetching images in loop in table of same column name

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi there I am trying to execute one code in which the images will be fetched in TABLE columns depending on the number of rows contained in the database of same column. Here i have used column name as a name to fetch the images.
Since there can be many columns of the same type so I have used loop to fetch the images from database of the same column. 
Here is my code

```
<?php
$connect=new mysqli("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($connect,'go-web');
$query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * from product WHERE name LIKE 'Groc%' ");
$result=mysqli_num_rows($query);
while($result!=0){
    echo '
    <td style="height:200px;width:20%;">
    <img src="<?php
    $query1=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT image from product where name like "Groc%"");
    $result1=mysqli_query($connect,$query1);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
    echo $row["image"];
    ?>" width="150px" height="150px" /><center><figcaption>Price:</figcaption></center><br>
    <center><figcaption>Stock:</figcaption></center></td>';
$result--;
}
?>
```

Any help?

Comment: So you echo php inside php?

Comment: Yea i am trying to do that. I am getting values successfully but not getting the images.

Comment: Why are you making the same query on each iteration in your `while()`-loop? Do the query outside of the loop, since it doesn't seem to be dependent on the first query. You should also look at the generated code. (view source in your browser). I don't think it will look as you expect.

Comment: But to get the images in table of the same column name I have to run a loop and keep fetching the images through loop instead doing manual right? And from the first query i am only taking the number of rows available using like operator. And the second query help us to get the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
 <?php
    $connect=new mysqli("localhost","root","");
    mysqli_select_db($connect,'database')
    $query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM table_name where name='$name'");
    echo "<table>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo '<tr><td style="height=100px"><a href=""><img src="'.$row['image'].'" width="150px" height="150px" /></a></td></tr>';
    }
    echo "</table>";

    ?>
```